# SSMS 32bit can't connect SSIS 64bit

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, ssis

I can't find the solution and searching for info doesn't give desired results

Environment:

- Server: W2K8 EE 64 bit + MSSQL SE 2K8 R2 64 bit
- Client: Windows XP Prof 32 bit

Using SSMS on client machine I get the following error:

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------

Cannot connect to <<server-name>>.

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Failed to retrieve data for this request. (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&LinkId=20476

------------------------------

A security package specific error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070721) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

------------------------------

A security package specific error occurred. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070721) (Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

When I connect from another 64bit W2K8 server using SSMS it works correctly.

Is there some workaround to make it work? For now I'm using SSMS on remote 64-bit machine, but would like to use it on local 32-bit PC.

Comment: I saw a couple blogs that may indicate it was fixed in R2... are you sure you have SSMS R2 where the problem occurs?

Comment: Yes. On 32-bit machine SSMS version 10.50.1817.0, on 64-bit SSMS version 10.50.1810.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finaly got it working. Not quite sure of explanation, but I think it had something to do with Kerberos / NTLM authentication.

SSIS was running under domain account that was not registered with SPN. Changing to "Log On as Built-in Account" as Network Service and restarting SSIS service solved the problem.

But also I'm (almost) sure that I've tried it earlier when I found his thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlintegrationservices/thread/bba0d02d-67d0-42d4-af20-5ea8a4ae443b

Also these articles explaining Kerberos, NTLM and checking SPN settings were helpful:

- http://sql-articles.com/articles/dba/linked-server-part-2/
- [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sql_protocols/understanding-kerberos-and-ntlm-authentication-in-sql-server-connections)